# What's the equivalent if/else statement for this multiply nested ternary expression?

Tags: c++, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm refactoring a chunk of code in Notepad++, and came across this in `parameters.cpp`

[image: Someone got really carried away with the ternary operator]

What is the equivalent series of `if`/`else` statements?

Comment: Could you post the code here instead of a screenshot?

Comment: I don't see what part is confusing you. Or, are you just asking what `(booleanExpression1) ? value1 : (booleanExpression2) ? value2 : value3` means?

Answer (score 3):

This seems more like a typing challenge than an actual question...

```
const TCHAR *pFolderStyleStr;

if ( svp._folderStyle == FOLDER_STYLE_SIMPLE )
    pFolderStyleStr = TEXT("simple");
else if ( svp._folderStyle == FOLDER_STYLE_ARROW )
    pFolderStyleStr = TEXT("arrow");
// (same for circle and none)
else 
    pFolderStyleStr = TEXT("box");
```

A `switch` would be better than an `if..else` here, however I see no reason to change the original code. "Refactor" doesn't mean "rewrite for the sake of it".

If you really do want to refactor then my advice would be to go:

```
const TCHAR *pFolderStyleStr = folder_style_string(svp._folderStyle);
```

and add a function:

```
const TCHAR *folder_style_string(WHATEVER_TYPE style)
{
     switch(style)
     {
     case FOLDER_STYLE_SIMPLE: return TEXT("simple");
     // ...
     default: return TEXT("box");
     }
}
```

Comment: +1. Re: "'Refactor' doesn't mean 'rewrite for the sake of it'": Would that there were more people who agreed with you about this . . .

Answer (score 0):

It would be equivalent to something like this:

```
if(folder_style == SIMPLE)
    text = "simple"
else if(folder_style == ARROW)
    text = "arrow"
//...more statements
else
    text = "box"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switch/case statement more effective than if/else for nested ternary expression.